# Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm following michael harlt rails tutorial but i get this error

> Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"

when previewing account activation

This is my user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email,  subject: "Account activation"
  end

  def password_reset
    @greeting = "Hi"

    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

and the error highlights the line that says

```
mail to: user.email,  subject: "Account activation"
```

I tried adding layout 'mailer' in user_mailer.rb but it doesn't work.

EDIT:
[Here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuW26.png)

[The screenshot of my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujyPp.png)

Comment: You need to add the actual erb.html (or any other variant you might have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already, you will need a folder within views called user_mailer and within that you will need a file for each of those methods (account_activation.html.erb & password_reset.html.erb). This is where the template of your email will be.

Comment: I have them, all html.erb files in views .

Comment: Do you have a github link for this project? or a screenshot of your mailers folder and views where you've placed these files?

Comment: I'm using bit bucket but i can screenshot it.

Comment: Yes please - would help if you could screenshot it. I just want to see the layout of the folders within view and your files in mailer folder.

Comment: Is the name account_activation or account_activations? of the file which is highlighted?

Comment: account_activation

Comment: i found out that the layout 'mailer' should be  'layout mailer'. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @wemode, that is equivalent to commenting out the line. In ruby, any literal value, like "string" or 42 does nothing.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, and it seemed to work for me if I commented out the layout 'mailer' line in application_mailer

eg

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'noreply@taskflow.herokuapp.com'
  # layout 'mailer'
end
```

Comment: Any idea why the `rails generate` command did not produce the layout files for us and it did for Michael Hartl?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is the next:

to generate this mailer you use this command

```
$rails generate mailer UserMailer account_activation password_reset
```

sending back

```
create  app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
invoke  erb
create    app/views/user_mailer
create    app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
create    app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
invoke  test_unit
create    test/mailers/user_mailer_test.rb
create    test/mailers/previews/user_mailer_preview.rb
```

by a strange way `app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb` file is not generated so when you call

> layout 'mailer'

the rails core send you this error

> "Missing template layouts/mailer"

you can resolve this by 2 ways.

First: comment out or delete  layout 'mailer'.

Second: Creating the file.

Another ways like 'layout mailer' are bad practices cause this syntax have no sense for Rails.

If you create the file, use this code to fill it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creating a blank file raised an exception. Creating one with just a HTML comment caused blank HTML view output (text worked fine). What content did you have in the file?

Comment: Thanks. Try using backticks - ` to mark text as code

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and what resolved it is ensuring I had two files in `.../app/views/layouts/`: `mailer.html.erb` and `mailer.text.erb`.

`mailer.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

`mailer.text.erb`:

```
<%= yield %>
```

Comment: What was the content of those files?

Comment: @TomHale, I've edited my response to include to contents of both files.

Comment: Excellent, this is the solution I went with. I believe it is the only one which works generically in the text-only case - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the file `app/mailers/application_mailer.rb`
From Hartl's tutorial:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
 default from: "noreply@example.com"
 layout 'mailer'
end
```

Comment: I do have that file with all user_mailers  templates in views

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserMailer` class, is still inheriting from the `ApplicationMailer` which defines the base layout directory as `layout 'mailer'`. For your current code and folder structure to work, you could make the following changes.

From this

```
UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
```

To this

```
UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
```