# Missing template layouts/<CUSTOM_MAILER_NAME> with {:locale=>[:en]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting below error while running ruby application.

```
18:46:35 resque.1 | Missing template layouts/test_mailer with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, 
:html, :builder, :ruby]}. Searched in:
  18:46:35 resque.1 |   * "/home/administrator/<PROJECT_PATH>/app/views"
  18:46:35 resque.1 |   * "/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby2.4.1/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.39/app/views"
  18:46:35 resque.1 |   * "/home/administrator/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views
```

Application having separate UI which is in Angular and back-end in Rails.
I'm using mailer for simply sending mail to user.

I found one similar question but I guess its still not match with my requirement.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398611/missing-template-layouts-mailer-with-locale-en-formats-html/38399907#38399907)
I already created test_mailer.rb inside mailers folder and also use layout specific to test_mailer.rb under views folder.

Still I'm getting above mentioned error.

Few more information:

**mailers/test_mailer.rb**

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
default from: 'test@gmail.com'
    layout 'test_mailer'
    def mail_notification(user, filename)
      @user = user
      @filename = filename

      mail(
        to: user.email,
        subject: "Testing Mail"
      )
    end
  end
```

**views/test_mailer/mail_notification.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <Mail_Text>  
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is for missing layout for mailer.

```
Missing template layouts/test_mailer with 
{:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, 
:html, :builder, :ruby]}
```

In third line of `mailers/test_mailer.rb` the statement says `layout 'test_mailer`

It looks for `test_mailer.html.erb` in your `views/layout` folder. You have to create this file with simple HTML Body like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now in `mail_notification.html.erb` only keep the email content and remove html body, it will be taken from layout file.

**Update**:
You might have confusion because name of your layout and your mailer class is same. Just for understanding you can rename your mailer layout name to `mailer_layout`:
ie:

```
class TestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'test@gmail.com'
    layout 'mailer_layout'

    def mail_notification
    ...
    end
end
```

Now you need following views:

> app/views/layouts/mailer_layout.html.erb
>
> app/views/test_mailer/mail_notification.html.erb

Comment: I have few confusion.
1. Do I need to add `mail_notification.html.erb` under `views/layouts/` or I need to create another folder parallel to `layouts` naming 'test_mailer' and need to put `mail_notification.html.erb` inside this folder.
2. If I follow second approach mentioned in question 1, then I'm getting same error again. Currently what I'm doing is like: creating `test_mailer.html.erb` inside `views/layouts` folder which contain simple HTML code mentioned in your answer. Also creating one more file naming `mail_notification.html.erb` inside `test_mailer` folder parallel to `layouts`.

Comment: Please let me know Is it proper way to do so?